# Composer: display custom message after package is upgraded to a version

Tags: composer-php

In a package I've introduced a change I'd like to be visible to all users upgrading from an older one through that version. So when composer upgrades the package it should show a message to the developer.

I've seen this in Yii2 but I cannot figure out how they do it. It seems composer is showing relevant portions of file [`framework/UPGRADE.md`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md), but I see no references to this file in composer docs or in `composer.json`. An Yii2 upgrade example:

```sh
$ composer update yiisoft/yii2
  - Updating yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.32 => 2.0.37): Loading from cache

  Seems you have upgraded Yii Framework from version 2.0.32 to 2.0.37.

  Please check the upgrade notes for possible incompatible changes
  and adjust your application code accordingly.

  Upgrade from Yii 2.0.36
  -----------------------

  * `yii\db\Exception::getCode()` now returns full PDO code that is SQLSTATE string. If you have relied on comparing code
    with an integer value, adjust your code.

...


  Upgrade from Yii 2.0.34
  -----------------------

  * `ExistValidator` used as a rule of `EachValidator` now requires providing `targetClass` explicitely and it's not possible to use it with `targetRelation` in
    that configuration.

...

  You can find the upgrade notes for all versions online at:
  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.37/framework/UPGRADE.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is feature of [`yiisoft/yii2-composer`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer) package, which is Composer plugin, so it can react on some Composer events. You may find details in [implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer/blob/c372400aa6b6f2c52a82764496b37eb50d6e479f/Plugin.php#L130). There is no shortcut for this, you need to implement it yourself.

But I would discourage to do this - Yii 2 is a framework and its architecture usually means that it is most important dependency in the project. Displaying such notice may be justified in case of Yii 2 (note that it displays only potential BC breaking changes in minor release, not all changes from changelog), but if every dependency would do this, it will result unreadable mess. If someone wants to track changes in updated dependencies, he can use [`pyrech/composer-changelogs`](https://github.com/pyrech/composer-changelogs).